# optimal Java Random seed

Tags: java, random

In regard to providing the `long` to seed `java.util.Random`, if I instantiate the object once, it seems that if I just take the time as a seed that will be satisfactory for the life of the program, which for my purpose means that the result of a series of calls to `nextDouble()` looks random.

Suppose for reasons of code simplicity, I instantiate `Random`, use it several times, then re-instantiate, and repeat.  If the seed is provided similarly, the seeds will be similar and increasing because it is based on the time. The increases will be small compared to the value if it is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.  (Edit: This question was asked in the year 2011.)

If I chain the output of `nextDouble()` does the re-instantiation of `Random` with a non-random time-based seed cause a subtle pattern to appear in the composite chain of output from `nextDouble()`.  Another way to phrase this question is: do I need a seed drawn uniformly from the set of `long`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably are likely to run into a situation like this where indeed they will get assigned the same seed, particuarly if they're created in the same millisecond. Some machines ahve a resolution as low as 15 milliseconds or more, so it becomes an even bigger problem.

One way toget around this is to use `Math.random()`. It uses a system wide random instance that only ever gets instantiated the first time it's used. I don't believe you have access to the underlying instance, so you can't use it to get `nextInt()` but you can use `Math.random()` for doubles, or if you really want your own Random object, get a `double` from `Math.random()`, convert its bits into a `long` and use that `long` as your seed for your new `Random`.

Oracle docs for random can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29).

```
// create new random with seed from system random
Random r = new Random(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Google. You linked me to the 1.4.2 documentation. Apparently you never got the memo that Java 7 is out?

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of adding java6 into all my google search queries for Java :-) Anyway, update to java6 link, at least.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how this is better than what Random does by default. ;) (see my answer)

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're absoltely right. I was under the impression it used `System.currentTimeMillis()` and I was entirely unaware of the internal seed it keeps. I suppose I could see some benefit to refactoring this in such a way that for testing purposes you consistently got the same seed, but that's a stretch. I definitely concede that this answer was based on a flawed assumption. But we're all here to learn right? :-)

Comment: @glowcoder From memory, Java 1.4.2 used System.currentTimeMillis() and it didn't use a counter.  Perhaps you are showing your Java age. ;)

Comment: @Peter :-( not exactly how I wanted to start my day!! But at least I'm not going crazy. I would imagine they decided to use `nanoTime` and the counter for this exact purpose? So people didn't have to do silly stunts like this to get good random generators?

Answer (score 4):

The automatically generated random seed uses System.nanoTime and a counter to ensure its always different.  IMHO, There is no need to play with the seed to improve Randomness

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

Random uses a 48 bit seed and repeats every 2^48 calls which means it cannot produce every possible `long` or `double` value.

Messing about with the seed sounds a bit like triple random strategies which don't actually help. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Random-Char-and-TriplyRandom-Double.aspx

If you want greater randomness, use SecureRandom which doesn't give the same random sequence even if you give it a seed of 1 every time.  This can produce every possible `long` and `double` value.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the generator of course but, in my experience, a small change to the seed has a large effect on the values that are generated.

It may well be detectable with a bit of work but, unless you're doing high-end statistical work or cryptography, it won't make a bit of difference.

In any case, if you *were* in that type of domain, you would have hardware-based random number generation, quite possibly using something like the 3 kelvin background radiation for a source :-)

Comment: Or a troll that sits in a cave shouting `Nine. Nine. Nine. Nine. Nine.` That's the trouble with random, you can never tell!

Comment: Try `Random random = new Random(441287210);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
    }` prints `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: And, if you keep going, you'll start getting different numbers. I'm not entirely certain what your point is, @Peter, unless it's to illustrate an interesting property of the expression used in the Java PRNG, since `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` has the same probability as `3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3` or `2 7 1 8 2 8 1 8 2 8`.