# Java Programming: Array's and Random Gen

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an assignment to create a program that generates random "poems". Here is my code:

```
package poem;

import java.util.Random;


public class Poem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rhyme1[] = {"ball", "call", "mall", "hall", "guy named Paul"};
        String rhyme2[] = {"cat","hat", "bat", "rat", "mat", "guy named Pat"};
        String nouns[] = {"you", "I", "girl", "boy", "man", "woman"};
        String verbs[] = {"run", "jump", "dive", "sink", "fall", "collapse", "swim", "love"};
        String others[] = {"like a", "into a", "nothing like a"};

        Random gen = new Random();

        String currentNoun = nouns[gen.nextInt(nouns.length)];
        String currentVerb = verbs[gen.nextInt(verbs.length)];
        String currentRhyme1 = rhyme1[gen.nextInt(rhyme1.length)];
        String currentRhyme2 = rhyme2[gen.nextInt(rhyme2.length)];
        String currentOther = others[gen.nextInt(others.length)];

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s \n", currentNoun, currentVerb, currentOther, currentRhyme1);
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s \n", currentNoun, currentVerb, currentOther, currentRhyme1);}}
```

My question is, when I run it I get the exact same line both times.
How do I get a different, randomly generated line every time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll want to look into a way to get random data, as the seed .

Comment: @Adel, That constructor should do a pretty good job of that.

Comment: tip: use `arrayLists`, much better

Comment: You can't really expect a variable to randomly change without reassigning it.

Comment: Well, isn't it because you actually have the same printf twice there?

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572147/optimal-java-random-seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're only calling gen.nextInt once per variable.  When you generate the random number and assign it to currentX thats the only time you're assigning it.  You should put both the string assignment and the sysout in a loop to both generate new random values as well as print them.

i.e. something like

```js
while (true) {
     int i = gen.nextInt(10);
     System.out.println("foo " + i);
}
```

Comment: I do not think it's a good idea to confuse newbies with *infinite* loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `currentNoun`, `currentVerb` etc once and then printing them twice. Their values don't change unless you reassign them before printing them again.

Answer (score 0):

The variables haven't changed from the first time you call `System.out.printf()` to the second, so you are just printing the same twice. One way around it is to create a generatePoems method that will print as many poems as you wish and then call it from the main method. That way the whole thing will be much cleaner and the code is relatively reuseable.

```
void generatePoems(int numberOfPoems){ //This block should be outside of the main method
  for (int i = 0; i<numberOfPoems;i++){

  String rhyme1[] = {"ball", "call", "mall", "hall", "guy named Paul"};
  String rhyme2[] = {"cat","hat", "bat", "rat", "mat", "guy named Pat"};
  String nouns[] = {"you", "I", "girl", "boy", "man", "woman"};
  String verbs[] = {"run", "jump", "dive", "sink", "fall", "collapse", "swim", "love"};
  String others[] = {"like a", "into a", "nothing like a"};

  Random gen = new Random();

  String currentNoun = nouns[gen.nextInt(nouns.length)];
  String currentVerb = verbs[gen.nextInt(verbs.length)];
  String currentRhyme1 = rhyme1[gen.nextInt(rhyme1.length)];
  String currentRhyme2 = rhyme2[gen.nextInt(rhyme2.length)];
  String currentOther = others[gen.nextInt(others.length)];
  System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s \n", currentNoun, currentVerb, currentOther, currentRhyme1);
  }
}
```

And your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  generatePoems(2);
  /* 2 is the number of poems you want to generate. Can be anything as long as its
  under 2147483647 */
}
```